# Android layout overlapping top status bar in custom theme

Tags: java, android, xml, themes

In my android app, I made a theme here because I just want to change the background image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyHomeTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_main</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The problem is that now the layout is going full screen. The top status bar that shows the battery, time, wifi icon, etc is going on top of the root layout. Before I set the theme, the layout fit right under the status bar.

Does anyone know how I can make it fit under the status bar?

Thanks.